# Is there any alternate view for dba_free_space view in Oracle server?

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to get the size of my oracle database in my application. But the query always throws socket timeout error. Is there any alternate view available instead of dba_free_space?

Comment: what's your query and exact error? you should aim to fix that, not avoid it

Comment: I am getting "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timeout" exception on running dba_free_space in my application. I am using Oracle this jdbc driver 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: if you run the query in sqlplus, how long does the response take? SET TIMING ON might help show this

Comment: also, try collecting data dictionary stats via SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DICTIONARY_STATS;  then try your query again

Comment: 1. recycle bin is not enabled in my oracle database, also query completes in very few seconds when running on sqlplus..
2.  EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DICTIONARY_STATS;
This is for gathering dictionary statistic and these are valid to run if we have performed any actions in our database (like upgrade etc)  and I do not think this is having any direct relation...

Comment: if the stats are stale, your queries will be less than performant, you're getting a timeout, so it COULD help - i'd also check your alert log for messages around this

Comment: does the error related to the version of the driver I am using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216129/discussion-between-anna-and-thatjeffsmith).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use other views to get space usage at database level (excluding temporary space) with:

```
with used as 
 (select sum(bytes/1024/1024) as used_mb 
  from dba_segments),
total as
 (select sum(bytes/1024/1024) as total_mb 
  from dba_data_files)
select 
 (select total_mb from total) as total_mb,
 (select used_mb from used) as used_mb, 
 (select total_mb from total)- (select used_mb from used) as free_mb 
 from dual;
```

Example:

```
SQL> with used as
  2   (select sum(bytes/1024/1024) as used_mb
  3    from dba_segments),
  4  total as
  5   (select sum(bytes/1024/1024) as total_mb
  6    from dba_data_files)
  7  select
  8   (select total_mb from total) as total_mb,
  9   (select used_mb from used) as used_mb,
 10   (select total_mb from total)- (select used_mb from used) as free_mb
 11   from dual;

  TOTAL_MB    USED_MB    FREE_MB
---------- ---------- ----------
      1570     980.25     589.75
```

Comment: Do we need to exclude temp usage when calculating free space?

Comment: I think we need 2 different queries because temporary tablespaces are distinct from permanent tablespaces. Most of the time permanent tablespaces are much larger than temporary ones.  And `dba_free_space` does not report free space in temporary tablespace; we should use `dba_temp_free_space` for that.

Comment: thank you for your valuable help. I have another clarification. V$TEMP_EXTENT_POOL, V$SORT_SEGMENT, V$TEMP_SPACE_HEADER - from these 3 tables which one we must use to see the temp tablespace size statistics?

Comment: V$TEMP_SPACE_HEADER is the better to have allocated and free space. V$SORT_SEGMENT gives details about current usage and maximum reached. V$TEMP_EXT_TOOL is about buffer cache usage and should not be used to check for allocated and free space.

Comment: So to find used bytes & used %, one should use v$sort_segment. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, see detailed example in https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=ora-01652-ora-01630#3721029171353.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216079/discussion-between-anna-and-pifor).